# JQuery Autocomplete with ashx

Tags: 2010, web-part, jquery-ui

I can't make autocomplete work with ashx and the handler is working fine.

Here's the scenario:
1- JQuery files are properly referenced
2- ashx is deployed in /layouts and working (got this to work using this [link](http://www.lifeonplanetgroove.com/blog/index.php/2010/10/15/adding-and-deploying-generic-handlers-ashx-to-a-sharepoint-2010-visual-studio-project/))
3- on the text box when autocomplete is invoked using the code below nothing happens (why?)
    `$("#<%=txtLocation1.ClientID%>").autocomplete("/_layouts/Test/HandlerTest.ashx")`

When a user types on the text box, it should search the list and returns the list item(s) based on the user input. The list has only two columns: (1) Location and (2) GMT. Search is based on location. The list is referenced on the same site collection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a few ideas:

1. Compare the control ID being inserted into your jQuery call and ensure it is *exactly* the same as the actual control ID in the page.  Often the two are different where one includes underscores and the other includes dollar signs.
2. Fire up [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) and check to see that your jQuery is even fetching
   the data and that the ashx is returning the data expected.

Comment: There was another js error that is preventing the auto-complete to work. Thanks dave, I forgot I still have this issue open. I'm closing this now.